# How to use wix's react-native-navigation popTo()?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

How do you implement the popTo(componentId) method from wix's navigation library?

I've tried:

```
testFunc = () => {
    Navigation.popTo({
      screen: "TestScreen"
    });
  };
```

and:

```
testFunc = () => {
    Navigation.popTo({
      component: {
        name: "TestScreen"
      }
    });
  };
```

Neither works. there's no documented examples in wix's documentation on github, or SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/screen-api?id=poptorootcomponentid-mergeoptions) the command is **Navigation.popTo(componentId)**;

**Can you try this**

```
testFunc = () => {
    Navigation.popTo("TestScreen");
  };
```